# Swift: Run singleton function in viewDidLoad() and in a callback, doesn't get the same results

Tags: swift, callback, singleton

I've made a class for my loading spinner (UIActivityIndicatorView) with a singleton that I want to call in my ViewController's viewDidLoad() and my callback function for my get request to the API. I have stripped the code a bit, so it's a bit easier to understand the problem.

**ProgressView.swift:**

```
import UIKit

public class ProgressView {
    var containerView = UIView()
    var progressView = UIView()
    var activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()

    class var shared: ProgressView {
        struct Static {
            static let instance: ProgressView = ProgressView()
        }
        return Static.instance
    }

    func showProgressView(view: UIView) {
        containerView.frame = view.frame
        containerView.center = view.center

        progressView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 80)
        progressView.center = view.center
        progressView.backgroundColor = UIColor.colorWithRGBHexWithAlpha(0x444444, alpha: 0.7)
        progressView.clipsToBounds = true
        progressView.layer.cornerRadius = 10

        activityIndicator.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)
        activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = .WhiteLarge
        activityIndicator.center = CGPointMake(progressView.bounds.width / 2, progressView.bounds.height / 2)

        progressView.addSubview(activityIndicator)
        containerView.addSubview(progressView)
        view.addSubview(containerView)

        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    }

    func hideProgressView() {
        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        containerView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

**ViewController.swift:**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var api : ArrayController?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        ProgressView.shared.showProgressView(view)

        api = ArrayController(delegate: self)
        api!.getAllCases({ () -> Void in
            println("API Success Callback")
            ProgressView.shared.hideProgressView()
        })
    }

}
```

I've added a success callback to my API call `.getAllCases(success: () -> Void)`, which is being ran whenever my GET request is finished. The console logs: "API Success Callback", but doesn't hide the loading spinner. I don't really know what to search for, but whenever I move the `ProgressView.shared.hideProgressView()` directly in the viewDidLoad(), then it works, but I want to run the `hideProgressView()` whenever I finished the GET request.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's happening that the closure in the `getAllCases` call is not executed in the main thread. To fix that, you can use:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    println("API Success Callback")
    ProgressView.shared.hideProgressView()
}
```

Comment: That works, thanks Antonio! I will read more about the dispatch_async() to understand, why it works that way.

Comment: You might also be in interested in reading [Common Background Practices](http://www.objc.io/issue-2/common-background-practices.html), or the entire [issue #2](http://www.objc.io/issue-2/index.html), focused on concurrent programming

Comment: Thanks Antonio, will do!